# Issue assigning phone number to new user MS Teams Powershell : Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment

Tags: powershell, automation, microsoft-teams

I am writing a script to automate the creation of resource accounts in MS Teams using PowerShell and by retrieving infos from Excel file.
After creating resource accounts and assigning licenses, i am trying to assign a phone number with the command

```
Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment -Identity "upn" -PhoneNumber "+33..." -PhoneNumberType CallingPlan
```

but I get the same error everytime :

> Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets.internal\Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment
> : The server responded with a Request Error, Status: NotFound

I seached on google and found that it might be a MS issue, did someone already encounter the same problem?

Comment: Hi, SO is for coding issues and issues related to coding. If the problem is a MS issue I'm affraid we can't help you

Comment: Hi @bluuf, thanks for your response! Actually I am not sure it is a MS issue. It might be related to coding. I don't really know the origin of the prblem. That is why I am asking If anyone has had this problem (and has solved it maybe) and can tell me if it is a coding or a MS issue

Comment: @Sarah - Could you please share the powershell module version which you are using?

Comment: Hello @Nivedipa-MSFT, I am using version 4.2.0 of MicrosoftTeams

Answer (score 0):

You might want to update your MicrosoftTeams module to 4.3.0 (current non-preview) release, restart your PowerShell session and retry.
They made some fixes to that cmdlet in that release.

Comment: @Sarah - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved with above suggestion or are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Hello @Nivedipa-MSFT, I updated the module and I have no longer the server error. However I still get an error. 
At the beginning of my script I create resource accounts and wait until the resources are created (with a while loop), then I get their AzureAD ObjectID.
Finally when I try the "Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment" command i get this error: 

"Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets.internal\Set-CsPhoneNumberAssignment : The user '7f54ff08-06a6-4df4-a287-adceb31af05d' is not found" but when I check the user exists

Comment: @SarahRezaiguia - Are you trying this command with user ID? Could you please test this command with UPN?

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your answers. I was able to find the solution to my problem.
The user was created in Azure, but I had to wait longer for it to be created in Teams. 
At first, I only did the test (a loop) on whether the user existed on AzureAD, and I thought it was enough. But then I did the test on whether it was created on Teams in order for the command to succeed and it worked.